# How to Get GPS data of a path by drawing on a Map

Tags: gps, gis

I need a data set of location points (Lat. and Lon.) is there any tool I can use where I can draw the path on a map and get the points as required format? Or is there any other easy way to do this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution check it out, and make sure add the external Jar and CSS resorses.

The HTML

```
<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height:500px" align="center"></div>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="getAllLocations();">GET ALL THE LOCATIONS</button>

    <div>
        <h3>Output Console</h3>

        <textarea id="TextArea" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
        <br>
```

The JS

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([ 6.88869, 79.85878 ], 18);

        L.tileLayer(
                        'https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                        {
                            maxZoom : 20,
                            attribution : 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, '
                                    + '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, '
                                    + 'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                            id : 'examples.map-i86knfo3'
                        }).addTo(map);

        var poly = L.polyline([], {
            color : 'green'
        });
        poly.addTo(map);

        map.on('click', function(e) {
            poly.addLatLng(e.latlng);

            //alert();
        });

        getAllLocations = function (){
alert ("Test");
    var locArray = poly.getLatLngs();
    var area = document.getElementById('TextArea');

    for(var i=0; i<locArray.length; i++){

        var item2 = locArray[i];
        var item3 = "" + item2;
        var item4 = item3.split("(");
        var item5 = item4[1].split(")")
        //alert(item5[0]);

        area.value += item5[0] + "\n";


    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZdLrb/13/